# "I who am" or "I whom am"?

Tags: grammar, whom

What is the correct usage of who/whom after the first person pronoun "I"?

> I ___ am most concerned, was not consulted.

I think it should be *who*, but I am not sure.

Comment: You could stick a _, who_ in to make it grammatical, but most people wouldn't use either. 'I was not consulted, and I am the person this affects the most.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't quite understand what you're trying to say. Can you please elucidate?

Comment: The choice of 'who' here (preceded by a comma, or with no commas in the sentence) makes it grammatically correct. But few native speakers would actually say (or even write) this; my rewrite might fit.

Comment: As others have said, the answer is unequivocally _who_. But for many people it is the _am_ which is problematic, because _who am_ is so rare as to feel "wrong". There's no other choice which seems to work (_who is_; _who are_) so people tend to avoid the expression. "I who have ... " is not nearly such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"who" works just fine.

But as Edwin Ashworth pointed out, this sentence is a bit too convoluted. It sounds very gothic and pretentious. People don't talk like that.

Comment: They [sing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(Who_Have_Nothing)) like that, though :P

Comment: @oerkelens Have you got your tense right there?

Comment: I daily sing that song, why? :D And the 60s may be long, long ago, but they are not "gothic" :P

Comment: @oerkelens - sure, but song lyrics aren't necessarily written the way people talk :) There's a certain poetry to it which people don't generally use in day-to-day dialogue. That is why I said "who" works grammatically. You *can* say it. It's just... no-one would actually say it like that :)